# Updating table rows with Flask and Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update the rows in a table by using Flask and jquery.

The application does not update the table row when I click the button with id="update-button" in the jquery section below..

This is my flask code to update the database:

```
@app.route('/update_process')
def update_process():

    firstName = request.args.get('firstName', 0, type=str)

    lastName = request.args.get('lastName', 0, type=str)

    fullName = Process.query.get(firstName,lastName)

    fullName.firstName = firstName

    fullName.lastName = lastName

    db.session.commit()

    result = process_schema.dump(fullName)

    return jsonify(result)
```

Jquery and ajax part for the frontend:

```
 $("#getProcess").bind("click", function () {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/get_process",
            function (data) {

            $(data).each(function (i,full) {
                  $("#result").append(`<tr><td id="data_id">` + full.id +
                  `</td><td><input type="text" name=firstName
                   id="firstName" value=`+ full.firstName +`>`
                        +`</td><td><input type="text" name=lastName
                   id="lastName" value=`+ full.lastName +`></td><td>`+
                      `<button id="update-button">Update</button>`

                     );  //update-button id to update selected row

                         });

            });

                                     });

        $("#update-button").bind("click", function () {


              $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/update_process',{

                firstName: $('input[name="firstName"]').val(),
                 lastName: $('input[name="lastName"]').val()
              }, function (data) {
                    $("#result").text(data.result)

                 });


                                          });
```

Comment: Aside from some formatting issues, your code looks ok for the most part. What issues are you having with it?

Comment: @Wondercricket The problem is that the table isn't updating when I press the button "update-button". Do I need to paste the html code too? Thanks.

Comment: It's always best to describe the exact problem you are having, along with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How your question currently is, it doesn't mention what your issue is - it only says you need help